# почему в визуал студио 2010 при отладке с заходом, с обходом И Т.Д. переходит на какой-то ассемблер и не мой код

Tags: c++, visual-c++, отладка

ХОТЯ ПОСТАВИЛ ГАЛОЧКИ ТОЛЬКО МОЙ КОД И ДРУГИЕ. всё перепробовал, но не могу просмотреть поэтапно как выполняется рекурсивная функция. Вот код.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int GetFibNumber(int Fiblndex)
{
  if (Fiblndex < 2)
    return Fiblndex;
  else // рекурсия, если Fiblndex >= 2
    return GetFibNumber(Fiblndex - 1) + GetFibNumber(Fiblndex - 2);
}

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter 0-based index of desired Fibonacci Number: ";
  int Index = 0;
  cin >> Index;

  cout << "Fibonacci number is: " << GetFibNumber(Index) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

доходит до скобки после `return 0`  и начинается такой код.

```
#else  /* WPRFLAG */
            __initenv = envp;
            mainret = main(argc, argv, envp);
#endif  /* WPRFLAG */

#endif  /* _WINMAIN_ */

            /*
             * Note that if the exe is managed app, we don't really need to
             * call exit or _c_exit. .cctor should be able to take care of
             * this.
             */
```

а потом вообще дебри, но до разбора рекурсивной функции так и не доходит.

Comment: Это вы уже попали в эпилог... Бряку на if (Fiblndex < 2) ставьте и будет вам радость.

Comment: Глупый вопрос - конфигурация отладочная?

Comment: Небось переполнение стека, да?